# Subtract two dataframes to get the value difference

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe on which I get a daily aggregate for particular dates.Below is the dataframe for the date `2018-02-11` where I have found out the mean, min, max, std

```
    cpu cpu cpu cpu mem mem mem mem load    load    load    load    drops   drops   drops   drops   latency latency latency latency gw_latency  gw_latency  gw_latency  gw_latency  upload  upload  upload  upload  download    download    download    download    sap_drops   sap_drops   sap_drops   sap_drops   sap_latency sap_latency sap_latency sap_latency
    mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std
date                                                                                                                                                                
2018-02-11  4.282442748 0   17  4.361148065 13.61068702 0   27  6.123815451 3.891450382 0   47.62   6.426298507 1.526717557 0   100 12.30842628 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Similarly I have another dataframe for the date `2018-02-12` for which I found the mean, min, max, std

```
    cpu cpu cpu cpu mem mem mem mem load    load    load    load    drops   drops   drops   drops   latency latency latency latency gw_latency  gw_latency  gw_latency  gw_latency  upload  upload  upload  upload  download    download    download    download    sap_drops   sap_drops   sap_drops   sap_drops   sap_latency sap_latency sap_latency sap_latency
    mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std
date                                                                                                                                                                
2018-02-12  5.726315789 0   21  2.938315053 22.30526316 0   23  3.581474037 6.06    0   44.75   6.798944285 0.5263157895    0   100 7.254762501 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Here is code below

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("metrics.csv", parse_dates=["date"])
df.set_index("date", inplace=True)
df_prev = df.loc['2018-02-11'].resample('D')['cpu', 'mem', 'load', 'drops', 'latency',
                                             'gw_latency', 'upload', 'download', 'sap_drops',
                                             'sap_latency'].agg(['mean', 'min', 'max', 'std']).fillna(0)

df_next = df.loc['2018-02-12'].resample('D')['cpu', 'mem', 'load', 'drops', 'latency',
                                             'gw_latency', 'upload', 'download', 'sap_drops',
                                             'sap_latency'].agg(['mean', 'min', 'max', 'std']).fillna(0)
```

Now I want to subtract the two dataframes to get the value difference for each of the column.This is what I do

```
df_diff = df_next.sub(df_prev, fill_value=0)
print(df_diff)
```

But it doesn't subtract anything and I also get the dates which doesn't make any sense since I only want the stats difference.

```
    cpu cpu cpu cpu mem mem mem mem load    load    load    load    drops   drops   drops   drops   latency latency latency latency gw_latency  gw_latency  gw_latency  gw_latency  upload  upload  upload  upload  download    download    download    download    sap_drops   sap_drops   sap_drops   sap_drops   sap_latency sap_latency sap_latency sap_latency
    mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std
date                                                                                                                                                                
2018-02-11  -4.282442748    0   -17 -4.361148065    -13.61068702    0   -27 -6.123815451    -3.891450382    0   -47.62  -6.426298507    -1.526717557    0   -100    -12.30842628    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2018-02-12  5.726315789 0   21  2.938315053 22.30526316 0   23  3.581474037 6.06    0   44.75   6.798944285 0.5263157895    0   100 7.254762501 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

As you can see it doesn't do any subtraction at all.Why is that happening?

PS I ultimately want to find out the percentage difference between the stats of the two dates.Is there any direct way to do that?

Comment: `df_next - df_prev.values` ?

Comment: @RafaelC wow that works!but any idea how do I find out the percentage difference?I tried something like this `df_diff_pt = ((df_next - df_prev.values)/df_prev)*100` but didn't work.

Comment: Posted as answer

Comment: @RafaelC yeah I know its just that Stackoverflow makes you wait for 10 minutes before accepting an answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the difference

```
df_next - df_prev.values
```

To get the `%` change,

```
(df_next - df_prev.values)/(df_prev.values) * 100
```

Comment: hey just one more question.If I have to remove date from the final answer, what do I do?I tried doing this `df_diff.to_csv("stats_diff.csv", index=False)`  while saving to .csv file but I still see the date.

Comment: I believe `df_diff.reset_index().drop("date", 1).to_csv("stats_diff.csv")` should work